# Adding an ArcGIS webmap into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, arcgis-online

I have a topographical map of the Netherlands from Esri. I was hoping if somebody could tell me how I could add this map to my QGIS.

The map can be found on:
https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7aea6fa913a94176a1074edb40690318

It even has its own URL:
https://www.arcgis.com/home/topo_basiskaart__28in_rd_29_-_webmap_1334843157778

Is there any way that I can add this map in my QGIS project?

I am using Qgis 2.18.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the URL, click on Topo -> [Basiskaarten/Topo (MapServer)](https://services.arcgisonline.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Basiskaarten/Topo/MapServer) and click on WMTS

[image]

The link is https://services.arcgisonline.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Basiskaarten/Topo/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

In QGIS, choose Add Layer/ Add WMS Layer -> New and enter in URL https://services.arcgisonline.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Basiskaarten/Topo/MapServer/WMTS

Result

[image]